# perl extract values from a http request

Tags: rest, perl, session, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a perl rest API. When http request receives to my program I want to extract values in above mentioned request.

I used following code to take a dump

```
warn "\n\n  request : " . MyCT::Util::dumper($self->resp);
```

Following result could find in the log file.
How can I extract "standalone" from this result?

```
Tue Feb 18 05:20:26 2020] [warn] [21783] [MyCT] 

request : $VAR1 = bless( {
  'outputSent' => 0,
  'headersSent' => 0,
  'autoFlush' => 0,
  'req' => bless( do{\(my $o = 196025568)}, 'MyCT::Base::Request' ),
  '_cookies' => {
    'sessionKey' => '1762839:c480474dd4f4623035e8f35b445e1aad:c9920499157cf9c2a7972f773d08b972:standalone'
  },
  'contents' => [],
  'active' => 1
}, 'MyCT::Base::Response' );
```

Comment: I don't know what this `MyCT` is. It seems to be a private library which might just be a binding to a C library. In this case check the documentation of `MyCT::Base::Request` if there is some interface for the feature you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One normally doesn't access an object variable directly, instead using the provided accessors provided by the object's class.

Seeing as you didn't provide information about the class, we are left with only the fragile, error-prone alternative.

```
my $session_key = $self->resp->{_cookies}{sessionKey};
```

One you have the session key, it's just a question of splitting on `:` and getting the fourth field.

```
( split(/:/, $sesion_key) )[3]
```